# Print list elements with comprehension (python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

This looks very simple, but I don't know how to do it.

I need print the elements from a list placed into a string. I'm trying to use list comprehension, but the interpreter raises a error.

```
print '%s (...) %s (...) %s%s (...)%s (...)'%(i for i in mylist)
```

I can't use    print '%s'%(i for i in mylist) because the string has not a regular structure. The code above has a syntax error. What is the crrect form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give more details, especially the structure of your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the list into a tuple instead:

```
print '%s (...) %s (...) %s%s (...)%s (...)' % tuple(mylist)
```

Demo:

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> print '%s (...) %s (...) %s%s (...)%s (...)' % tuple(mylist)
a (...) b (...) cd (...)e (...)
```

Alternatively, use the [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead to format your string:

```
print '{} (...) {} (...) {}{} (...){} (...)'.format(*mylist)
```

`.format()` also supports indexing into the list:

```
print '{0[0]} (...) {0[1]} (...) {0[2]}{0[3]} (...){0[4]} (...)'.format(mylist)
```